# C# How do I access the second half of the rectangle structure's coordinates

Tags: c#, xna, rectangles

This may be a simple question but I can't seem to find the answer after googling or going on the MSDN!

I have defined a rectangle using the following:

```
gridSecondRect3 = new Rectangle(324, 172, 471, 304);
```

I understand the first 2 number are the stating x & y, and the last 2 are the finishing x&y of the rectangle.

I understand how to access the first two using gridSecondRect3.X  (or .Y)

However, I would like to know how to access the last 2 numbers.

I've tried using the .Height  & .Width operators, however it didn't work.

Comment: just out of curiosity, have you _ever_ got an acceptable answer to your questions? I noticed you asked 13 questions, and none have an answer marked...

Comment: You should be aware that the third and fourth arguments to the `Rectangle` constructor are *not* the coordinates for the rectangle's bottom right corner.  They are, in fact, the width and height of the rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Right](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.right.aspx) and [Bottom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.bottom.aspx) properties.

[Rectangle.Right Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.right.aspx)

> Returns the x-coordinate of the **right side** of the rectangle.

[Rectangle.Bottom Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.bottom.aspx)

> Returns the y-coordinate of the **bottom of the rectangle**.

Comment: That's what I thought. The reason I need this is because I'm programming for touch input on a windows phone, I'm using rectangles so i can check what part of my chess board the user has touched. When I input the numbers manually it works, however when I add the .bottom and .right it allows me to click outside of the rectangle so I didn't think it was correct